# Deploying Rails App Using Capistrano - Rbenv version issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv, capistrano3

I am trying to deploy my Rails App to Server using capistrano...

But I am facing an issue with rbenv version...

Here is my Capfile

```
require 'capistrano/setup'

require 'capistrano/deploy'

require 'capistrano/rbenv'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'

set :rbenv_custom_path, '/home/renil/.rbenv'

Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

I got the rbenv path from **which rbenv** and set custom path

> set :rbenv_custom_path, '/home/renil/.rbenv'

In my deploy.rb file, I set

> set :rbenv_ruby, '1.9.3p484'

But when I am running **cap production deploy:setup_config** I am getting the following error...

```
DEBUG [0656253d] Finished in 3.246 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
ERROR rbenv: 1.9.3p484 is not installed or not found in /home/renil/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3p484
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `set :rbenv_ruby, '1.9.3-p551'`. Notice the dash.

If this doesn't help, make sure you have that version installed on your server. `rbenv install 1.9.3-p551`.